# Linq Grouping and workaround data entry errors in groups

Tags: c#, linq

In The Following Table i want to Group by ItemNo & ItemName. For Same ItemNo, ItemName should be typical, but due to data entry errors sometimes they are different : For Item#1 Name should be Name_11 Not ItemName_12. So it creates two groups. In such case for same ItemNo i want to take First ITemName

| ItemNo | ItemName | Other Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item#1 | Name_11 | Other |
| Item#1 | Name_12 | Other |
| Item#2 | Name_21 | Other |

Here is the code that need modification :

```
var _qry = _models
  .GroupBy(x => new { 
     x.ItemNo, 
     x.ItemName
   })
  .Select(y => new {
     ItemNo   = y.Key.ItemNo,
     ItemName = y.Key.ItemName,
     Other1   = y.Count(x => x.ID != 0),
     Other2   = y.Count(x => x.ID != 0 && (x.Completed == false || x.Completed == null))
   })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: You say you're having problems with inconsistent input data, but you're not showing us this data. Instead you show us clean data. Show us the exact data you have in one table and how you expect to group it in another table.

Comment: @Good Night Nerd Pride
As Per the table ItemName column second row should be Name_11 not Name_12

Comment: Then why not just group by `ItemNo` only?

Comment: because ItemNo is a number (Numbers & Letters) so ItemName clarify and define what is this number mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ItemName` from grouping key and get name from first item in the group.

```cs
var _qry = _models
  .GroupBy(x => new { 
     x.ItemNo
   })
  .Select(y => new {
     ItemNo   = y.Key.ItemNo,
     ItemName = y.First().ItemName,
     Other1   = y.Count(x => x.ID != 0),
     Other2   = y.Count(x => x.ID != 0 && (x.Completed == false || x.Completed == null))
   })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: It worked. Nice workaround. Thanks